# python beautifulsoup scrape site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to learn Python to scrape a websites lunch menu using beautifulsoup. I have made the request

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

And the response looks like this:

```
<div class="lunchRow">
<div class="lunchRowDay"><h3>Monday</h3></div>
<div class="lunchRowItem"><div class="lunchRowItemActual">Meatballs</div>
<div class="lunchRowItemActual">Soup</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="lunchRow">
<div class="lunchRowDay"><h3>Tuesday</h3></div>
<div class="lunchRowItem"><div class="lunchRowItemActual">Chicken</div>
<div class="lunchRowItemActual">Pork</div>
<div class="lunchRowItemActual">Fish</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What is the easiest way to get the lunchRowItemActual for each day? I started by searching for the day and get the next div but after that I am lost and I assume this is not the way to solve it.

```
soup = soup.find(string="Monday").find_next('div').contents[0].text
```

Comment: Get all `lunchRow` divs and search for an `h3` and `lunchRowItemActual` in them.

Answer (score 3):

First off you should try to get all lunchRow divs by their classname and save them to a variable like so:

```
rows = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'lunchRow'})
```

Then we can loop over them and get the individual days and items as follows. Here we get the first/only lunchRowDay item and then look for all lunchRowItemActual elements inside our current row:

```
for row in rows:
  print(row.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lunchRowDay'}).text)
  actuals = row.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'lunchRowItemActual'})
  for actual in actuals:
    print(actual.text)
```

Output of this is:

```
Monday
Meatballs
Soup
Tuesday
Chicken
Pork
Fish
```

Instead of printing them out you most likely want to put them in a dict using the lunchRowDay as the key and then putting the lunchRowItemActual values into a list but that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

soup.select is a great way to do things like this

then use get_text to... get the text

and some list comprehension will apply get_text to the whole list

```
days = soup.select("div.lunchRowDay")
for day in days:
    print(day.get_text())
    items = [item.get_text() for item in day.select("div.lunchRowItemActual")]
    print(items)
```